# Comparing date strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to see whether an item in my array was created today, so I'm using an arrayFilter to filter each element in my array, the problem is, I can't get my filter to work properly:

```
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.enquiries(), function (enquiry) {
    var include = true;

    if (self.onlyToday()) {
        var formatted = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date());

        include = include && +enquiry.EnquiryDate.indexOf(+formatted > -1);
    }

    return include;
});
```

Here is what my data looks like:

```
formatted: 26/11/2012
enquiry.EnquiryDate: 08/11/2012 08:46:46
```

So obviously, this `enquiry` should be filtered as it wasn't created today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. You're putting a string in `formatted`, then later using `+formatted > -1`. `+formatted` will always be `NaN`, which is never `> -1` (it's also never equal to `-1` and never `< -1`).
2. You're setting `include` to `true` and then doing `include = include && ...`. The part following the `&&` will never be evaluated, because the part to the left of `&&` is `true` and JavaScript (like most modern languages) short-circuits expressions.
3. If `enquiry` refers to an object, `+enquiry` will probably be `NaN` unless you've overridden its `valueOf`.
4. You're comparing *strings*, which means the most significant parts of the comparison will be on the left — but your date strings are in a format where the most significant values are on the *right*. So for example, the *string* `"01/01/2013"` is **less than** the *string* `"02/02/2012"`, even though of course that's not true of the dates they represent. If you want to meaningfully compare date *strings*, they must have the year on the left, followed by the month, followed by the day.

Based on your quoted `enquiry.EnquiryDate` string, you can do this:

```
var today = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy/mm/dd", new Date());
return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.enquiries(), function (enquiry) {
    var parts, enqDate;

    parts = enquiry.EnquiryDate.split(' ')[0].split('/');
    enqDate = parts[2] + '/' + parts[1] + '/' + parts[0];
    return enqDate === today;
});
```

Notes on the above:

- Note that I'm getting today's date with the year on the left.
- I've removed the `self.onlyToday()` bit because the filter didn't do anything if `self.onlyToday()` was false. My guess is you want that check outside this filter function, and you're either going to call this filter, or not.
- Since `enquiry.EnquiryDate` is a date *and* time string, separated with a space, first we split it on a space, then we take the first part (the date) and split it on the `/`. Then we recombine that in `yy/mm/dd` order.
- Now we know we can do the `===` on the strings to see if the enquiry date equals today.

You could, of course, do this comparison using `Date` objects, but as you'd just have to parse the `enquiry.EnquiryDate` strings into `Date` objects anyway, and you only want day resolution (not millisecond resolution), using a string compare seems reasonable.